# CSS Spacing multiple divs within multiple lines

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs per row. What I want to do is to just give a small space between the divs. So I added a margin-left. That affects all the first divs on each line.

Result:

```
[DIV1] -- [DIV2] -- [DIV3]
-- [DIV4] -- [DIV5] -- [DIV6]
```

What I want to get:

```
[DIV1] -- [DIV2] -- [DIV3]
[DIV4] -- [DIV5] -- [DIV6]
```

Css:

```
.grids_1{
    text-align:center;
    padding: 2% 0;
}
.grid_1{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 3%;
    float: left;
}
.grid_1.bg1{
    background: #505050;
}
.images_1 {
    width: 30.333%;
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

All the information within the divs are retrieved from the database. So I use PHP and a while loop to show all the divs.

Is there any way to add space between them without affecting the first div of each line?

Comment: Which CSS class is set to what element? Where is your HTML-code?

Comment: The best would be if you can post a jsfiddle link

Comment: I used the "nth-child(4n)" so that every fourth div would have a margin-left with 0%. That works perfect. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a known number of divs (3 in your example) you could remove margin for every fourth child with `:nth-child()`.

```
.images_1:nth-child(4n) { 
    margin: 0;
}
```

Reference: [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: You save my life. Thank you so much, that helped me a LOT. I didn't know that we have such option using CSS. Glad I know how to fix those kind of problems now.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your css:

```
.grid_1:nth-child(3n){ 
       margin-left: 0 !important; 
    }
```

this will set the margin-left to 0 on .grid_1 for element 0,3,6...

Comment: Thanks cari. emmanuel suggested the same thing and it works perfectly.